# Como accedo a un valor desde un puntero

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo una cuestión de acceso a un valor concreto a través de un puntero; Ilustremos que tengo:

```
int a=0U, *a_00=(void*)&a,
          *a_01=(void*)&a_00,
          *a_02=(void*)&a_01,
          *a_03=(void*)&a_02; *(int *)a_03=1U;
printf("%i\n", *(int *)a_00);
printf("%i\n", a);
```

Quiero acceder o cargar información a la variable `a` que estoy apuntando a través del puntero `a_03`.
Tengan en cuenta que no puedo acceder a `a_00`,`a_01`,`a_02` ya que no puedo modificar las funciones que me entregaron.

Le agradezco la colaboración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un nivel de indirección por cada variable intermedia; tienes 4 variables (`a_00`, `a_01`, `a_02`, `a_03`), por lo tanto son **4 asteriscos `*`**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    int a=0U, *a_00=(void*)&a,
              *a_01=(void*)&a_00,
              *a_02=(void*)&a_01,
              *a_03=(void*)&a_02;

    ****(int ****)a_03=1U;

    printf( "%i\n", ****(int ****)a_03 );
    printf( "%i\n", a );

    return 0;
}
```

> 1
> 1

Comment: Ok Gracias, esta es la que me funciono.